# CSS selectors not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am creating a table using Javascript and jQuery, and I want it so that when you click the td's on the first row of the table, then the rest of the td's in that column drop down. Let me try to explain it by showing my code. Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    createTr(heights);  
});

function createTr (heights) {
    for (var h=0; h<heights.length; h++) {  // h is row number, i is column number!
        var theTr = $("<tr>", { id: "rowNumber" + h});
        for (var i=0; i<heights.length-3; i++) { // IF EXTRA TD'S ARE SHOWING< CHANGE 3 TO SOMETHING ELSE
            theTr.append($("<td>", { "class": "row"+h + " column"+i,
                                     html: heights[h][i]
                                   }));
        }
        $('#newTable').append(theTr); // append <tr id='rowNumber0'> to the table, which is in the html

        if (h != 0) {
            $('.row' + h).addClass('invisible'); // hide all the rows except the first row
        }
        $('.column0').removeClass('invisible'); // show the first column
        $('.row0').not('.column0').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).addClass('column0Hover');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).removeClass('column0Hover');
            }
        });
    } // end for
} // end function
```

This basically creates td's and each td is similar to this format

```
<td class="rowh columni">
```

The parameter 'heights' is just an array, for example, it can be

```
var heights = [['headerOne', 'headerTwo'], ['someTd', 'anotherTd'],];
```

and it would create a table using those words, headerOne and headerTwo would be in the first row, someTd and anotherTd would be in the second row.

I want it so that the td in .row0 .column0 has a background color of red by default. It's so weird because `$('.row0').not('.column0').on({` doesn't select the td with `.row0` `.column0`, and `.row0` selects it, and .`column0` selects it, so it's class For Sure is `.row0` `.column0`, however, when I go to the CSS and do

```
.row0 .cloumn0 {
    background-color: #063 !important;
}
```

it doesn't work. And when I try to select it as a query selector like so

```
$('.row0 .column0')
```

it still doesn't select anything. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.row0 .column0` selects elements with the class `column0` which are descendants of elements with the class `row0`.

`.row0.column0` selects elements with the class `column0` **and** `row0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version that I use for table toggles:

```
<body>
    <style>
      #myTable tbody{display:none;}
      #myTable th:hover{cursor:pointer;}
    </style>

    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rel="row1" colspan="2">My row title 1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="row1">
          <tr>
            <td>My Data 1</td>
            <td>My Data 2</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rel="row2" colspan="2">My row title 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="row2">
          <tr>
            <td>My Data 1</td>
            <td>My Data 2</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#myTable').on('click','th',function(){
          var link = $(this).attr('rel');
          $('#' + link).toggle();
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
```